# Why is "insert" of unordered_set Undefine Behavior here?

Tags: c++, stl, c++17

I am sorry for my fuzzy title.

Suppose there are some pointers of nodes, and I want to collect the nodes' pointers with unique `value`.

```cpp
struct node_t
{
    int value;
    node_t(int v = -1) : value(v) {}
};
```

For example, if we have 4 pointers:

```
p1 points to node(1)
p2 points to node(1)
p3 points to node(2)
p4 points to node(2)
```

then I want to collect `{p1, p3}` here.

And this is what my code wrote:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <unordered_set>
#include <algorithm>
using namespace std;
struct node_t
{
    int value;
    node_t(int v = -1) : value(v) {}
};
struct myequal
{
    bool operator()(const node_t *p1, const node_t *p2) const
    {
        return p1->value == p2->value;
    }
};
int main()
{
    unordered_set<node_t *, hash<node_t *>, myequal> table;
    node_t n1(0), n2(0);
    table.insert(&n1), table.insert(&n2);
    cout << (&n1) << '\n';
    cout << (&n2) << '\n';
    cout << table.size() << '\n';
    cout << *table.begin() << '\n';
}
```

I run the code on MacOS12, compile it with `clang++ -std=c++17 xxx.cpp`, but its output is unsure.

Sometimes it outputs:

```cpp
0x7ff7bad974e0
0x7ff7bad974d0
1
0x7ff7bad974e0
```

But sometimes it outputs:

```cpp
0x7ff7b4bdc4e0
0x7ff7b4bdc4d0
2
0x7ff7b4bdc4d0
```

Why do this happen?

According to the [document](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/unordered_set/unordered_set/insert/) of `unordered_set`,

> Each element is inserted only if it is not equivalent to any other element already in the container (elements in an unordered_set have unique values).

Comment: Output looks about right. `&n1` is the memory address of `n1`. You are just printing that. The first two lines of the output are the two memory addresses of `n1` and `n2`. Fourth line is same. `*table.begin()` is a pointer to a memory address and you are printing a pointer there.

Comment: You are using pointers as keys, and key storage is based on hashes. You are hashing the pointers themselves, not the node values they point to. But you are using the node values for key equality. You have 2 nodes with the same value, so in theory the table size should be 1, but the 2 nodes are hashing differently. I think that inconsistency is causing the behavior you are seeing.

Comment: Hashes of equivalent elements must be equal. So, if you define custom equality you have to also define corresponding custom hash.

Comment: I don't see it mentioned on cplusplus.com (your documentation source), but if you head over to cppreference.com's [documentation for unordered set](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_set), there is a link to the named requirement [UnorderedAssociativeContainer](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/UnorderedAssociativeContainer). The relevant info is the third paragraph (a single line, just before the "since C++20" box). I hope I just overlooked something on cplusplus.com, since this is kind of important information for people writing their own equality operators.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The short version is that your hash and equality operations are incompatible. When you insert an element, first the hash is taken, then the bucket for that hash is checked to see if an equivalent element is present.

Let's say there are three buckets named A, B, and C. You insert `n1` and it ends up in, let's say, bucket B. Next you insert `n2`.

- If `n2` gets hashed to bucket B, then the equivalent `n1` is found in that bucket, so `n2` is not inserted.
- If `n2` gets hashed to bucket A (or C), then that bucket – and only that bucket – is checked to see if the element already exists. Bucket A is empty, so of course no equivalent element is found. So `n2` is inserted.

To make your hash and equality operations compatible, equal things must compute to the same hash. That ensures that equal things will be assigned to the same bucket (ensures that `n2` gets hashed to bucket B in the above example). If equality is based upon `p1->value`, then the hash better be based upon `p1->value`.

Documentation from [cppreference.com](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/UnorderedAssociativeContainer):

> If two **Keys** are equal according to **Pred**, **Hash** must return the same value for both keys.